# Handling selection of buttons + adding selected items to new array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with a set of arrays which are printed to the screen as buttons via an API call.

I am looking to add my bases/frostings buttons (select one) and then add the key of each one selected to a new OrdersArray. I also need to be able to select multiple toppings (multi-select) and add those to a nested array within the OrdersArray.

I would like to also change the colors of each selected button when they are selected.

My Buttons function generates the buttons.

```
function Buttons({ list }) {
  const style = {
    display: 'inline-block',
    textAlign: 'center',
    border: '1px solid black',
    padding: '10px',
    margin: '10px',
    width: '35%'
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {list && list.map(item =>
            <button key={item.key} 
            style={style} 
            >
                {/* <p>{item.key}</p> */}
                <p>{item.name}</p>
                <p>${item.price}.00</p>
                {/* <p>{item.ingredients}</p> */}
            </button>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

My app component renders the buttons.

```
Class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
          super();

          this.state = {
              'basesObject': {},
              'frostingsObject': {},
              'toppingsObject': {},
              selectedButton: null
          }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.getBases();
        this.getFrostings();
        this.getToppings(); 
      }

      /* GET DATA FROM SERVER */
      getBases() {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/cupcakes/bases')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(results => this.setState({'basesObject': results}))
      }

      getFrostings() {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/cupcakes/frostings')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(results => this.setState({'frostingsObject': results}))
      }

      getToppings() {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/cupcakes/toppings')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(results => this.setState({'toppingsObject': results}))
      }

render() {
    let {basesObject, frostingsObject, toppingsObject} = this.state;  

    let {bases} = basesObject; 
    let {frostings} = frostingsObject; 
    let {toppings} = toppingsObject; 

    return (          
      <div>
        <h1>Choose a base</h1>
        <Buttons on 
         list={bases}
        />
        <h1>Choose a frosting</h1>
        <Buttons
         list={frostings}
        />
        <h1>Choose toppings</h1>
        <Buttons
         list={toppings}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm new to React, any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a function to the buttons that will modify a state value in the parent component when the button is clicked.

In parent:

```
const addToOrder = item => {
orderArray.push(item);
const newOrder = orderArray.reduce((acc, order) => {
  return acc + " " + order.name;
}, "");
setOrder(newOrder);
};
...
<Button addToOrder={addToOrder} />
```

In Button.js

```
<button onClick={() => addToOrder(item)} >
```

[Check out the whole thing in this Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-http-mits9)

For keeping track of which ones have been clicked you'll need to keep track of button state either in the button component itself or in the parent container if you want to keep the buttons stateless.  Then set the button attribute disabled to true or false based on that state.

```
<button disabled={isButtonDisabled} />
```

Sorry I didn't have time to flesh the full thing out, but this should get you in the right direction.